# Oracle - Mysterious indexes

Tags: oracle, index

I have a table in Oracle 10.2g that I'm trying to import roughly 11 million rows into. The table contains an `SDO_GEOMETRY` column. It previously had `NOT NULL` constraints on all 3 columns, a primary key constraint on a `NUMBER(38,0)` column, and a spatial index. I have removed all of these to speed up the import. I removed the primary key constraint using `ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT` with the additional parameter `DROP INDEX`.

However, selecting on `USER_INDEXES` reveals there are currently two indexes on the table with very strange names: `SYS_IL0000471920C00009$$` and `SYS_IL0000471920C00010$$`. Their `INDEX_TYPE`s are both `LOB`, and they both have `UNIQUE` for their `UNIQUENESS` column. `COMPRESSION` is `DISABLED`. They are both `VALID`, non-`TEMPORARY`, and `GENERATED` (though I'm not sure what `GENERATED` means).

Where might these indexes have come from? Could dropping them cause problems?

Comment: `GENERATED` shows whether the object name was automatically generated by the system or assigned by you explicitly when you created the constraint (index). See [`ALL_INDEXES`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1106.htm#i1578369) in Database Reference.

Comment: So basically, these indexes come from some constraint I placed on the table, and the way Oracle implements that constraint involves an index. So it automatically generated one, and for some reason, they weren't deleted when I removed the constraint?